# Set Custom Views for Slim after it's been instantiated

Tags: php, slim

I'm working on a very old legacy website(think PHP 4 constructs). Slowly but surely I'm refactoring most of the code. Since it's not really a huge amount of code I decided to use Slim.

I'm using Custom Views, and probably in the near future I'll go for a tempting engine, probably Twig.

Long story short, I'm autoloading the Custom Views folder to have them ready wherever. As far as my understanding of Slim goes, to use the Custom View I need to do the following:

```
$app = new Slim(array(
    'view' => 'CustomView'
));
```

This is all nice and easy to use, however I'd like to have(if that's even possible) Slim loaded as a property of a some base class(along with other things) and have other classes extend that one. Clearly this presents problems since I can only have a single Custom View.

Is there some other way of passing in the Custom View to Silm, after it's instantiated?

Possibly something like:

```
$app = new Slim();

$app->setView(Custome View Goes Here);
```

I couldn't find anything relevant on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work. Example taken from [documentation.](http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/settings/#view)

> The View class or instance used by the Slim application. To change this > setting after instantiation you need to use the Slim application's  view() method.

```
// During instantiation
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \My\View()
));

// After instantiation
$app->view(new \My\View());
```